# Angular clickable list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a clickable list in angular, after clicking on the item, it should fire a function in controller where I want to manipulate the item.
The code is:

```
<h2>User List</h2>
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
            <ul>
                 <li>
                      <div  ng-click="getUserChat(key)">
                          <a>{{key}}</a>
                      </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
```

in controller:

```
chatApp.controller('chatController', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$state', '$http' , function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $http) {
$scope.init = function(){
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_list/").success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
        console.log($scope.items);
    });
};
$scope.getUserChat = function(selectedFriend){
    $rootScope.selectedFriend = selectedFriend;
    console.log($rootScope.selectedFriend);
}
}]);
```

But the console.log is not showing anything, that is the associated function getUserChat is not called. It's also not showing any error in console.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle that demonstrates your issue, since your approach is correct. There should be no issue, like seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/nPRRB/2/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're using (key,value) in your expression, you could just do this...

```
<li ng-repeat="item as item.name in item">
```

(assuming you want to display a property of the item called "name" in the template, you may want to display something else).

Then, you just pass the whole item to the function...

```
<div  ng-click="getUserChat(item)">
```

So that the function has access to everything.

Also, not sure whether ng-click works on a div, maybe that is why your function isn't being called.